# Google Sheet Custom Function not getting populated from AppScript

Tags: google-apps-script, google-sheets

I am trying to create a portfolio tracker in google sheets. For that I have written a custom function in App Script. The function is taking two inputs - ticker symbol (tickers) and amount (values). Whenever I try to call the function in excel sheet, it is throwing an error as 'Reference does not exist'

```
function MyPortfolio(tickers, values) 
{
  
  var total = []
  var sums = {}

  for (i=0;i<tickers.length; i++)
  {  
    var t = tickers[i].toString()
    if(t!="Cash")
    {
      if(t in sums)
      {
        sums[t]+=Number(values[i])
      }
      else
      {
        sums[t]=Number(values[i])
      }
    }

  }
  for(var ticker in sums)
  {
    if(sums[ticker]>0)
    {
      total.push[ticker, sums[ticker]]
    }
  }
  return total
}
```

Need help

Comment: why excel sheet ? this seems to be a google sheet script!

Comment: sorry, it's google sheet only, not excel sheet.
By excel, I meant I am calling the function in google sheets

Comment: where is the error ? `if(t in sums)` sums has no values

Comment: I am new to this and don't know the source of error

Answer (score 0):

An empty array is not a valid return value.

Make sure that **total** is not empty.

If you do not want to return a value, you can return an array with empty values **["",""]**.

Comment: Array is not empty.
Value is getting stored in this code 
total.push[ticker, sums[ticker]]
And then I am returning total

Comment: Can you show me the value of "total" that the function is returning?

Answer (score 0):

The issue is resolved. It was a syntax error

```
.
.
total.push([ticker, sums[ticker]])
.
.
```

I forgot to put round brackets `(...)`